# JQuery post request failing without alert after post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have post request

```
var prodId = getParameterByName('param');
        var pass = $('#password1').val();
        $.post("rest/forget/confirm", {
            "param" : prodId,
            "password" : pass
        }, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }).done(function() {
            alert("second success");
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        }).always(function() {
            alert("finished");
        });

});
```

I obtain in alert "error" and "finished" but if i add `alert("lala");` code:

```
 var prodId = getParameterByName('param');
            var pass = $('#password1').val();
            $.post("rest/forget/confirm", {
                "param" : prodId,
                "password" : pass
            }, function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }).done(function() {
                alert("second success");
            }).fail(function() {
                alert("error");
            }).always(function() {
                alert("finished");
            });
            alert("lala");
    });
```

in alert i obtain  "lala" after my data then "second success" and "finished". Also if i debug this function without alert it works too.
why i get error in alert is missing, how i get successful without alert?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: what does `debug without alert` mean? Why have you not posted any details found when inspecting request in network tab of browser console? Also why aren't you using arguments of `error` for more dteails

Comment: why i get error in alert is missing, how i get successful without error

Comment: what does the browser console say?

Comment: console is clear, this method work in i set break point and move step by step even alert is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add property async :false in your ajax call.

Comment: but you have to remember that this is not so very well.